# Spring ApplicationListener on cluster

Tags: java, spring

There is a simple solution to implement Observer pattern in spring using ApplicationListener. But what if I need to use it in clustered environment? There is a load balancer and there are several application nodes. How can I make sure that event created on node A will reach node B and C and will be served there?

Comment: What I would do is to generate the Event and send it on a queue
All nodes can be consumers of these queues and so then can consume the new message and generate the relative event

Comment: So you think of the event replication?

Comment: Yes.. Maybe you may use also spring cloud bus (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/) but basically it relies on the same concept

Comment: That isn't what the `ApplicationListener` and `ApplicationEventPublisher` where designed for. However you could of course create a listener that puts stuf on a queue (jms, rabbit etc) and have the other nodes listen to that and re-publish the event. However you probably are better of by using a specialized mechanism which also makes clear that you are using async communication.

Comment: @JiKra did you manage to handle this?